# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows in function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Select statement return more than one row in resault. Is it possible get all row in resault with this function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_EMP AS

    TYPE measure_record IS RECORD(
       ename VARCHAR2(50), 
       sal VARCHAR2(50), 
       empno number);

    TYPE measure_table IS TABLE OF measure_record;

    FUNCTION get_emp(id NUMBER)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_EMP AS

    FUNCTION get_emp(id number)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED IS

        rec  measure_record;

    BEGIN
        SELECT ename, sal, empno
          INTO rec
          FROM emp where deptno = id;   
        PIPE ROW (rec);
       

    RETURN;
    END get_emp;
END;

SELECT * FROM table(PKG_EMP.get_ups(30));
```

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...` is for a single row.

If you want multiple rows then either:

- use `SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ... FROM ...` and iterate through the collection; or
- use a cursor and iterate through the row set.

For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_EMP AS
  FUNCTION get_emp(
    id number
  ) RETURN measure_table PIPELINED
  IS
    rec  measure_table;
  BEGIN
    SELECT ename, sal, empno
    BULK COLLECT INTO rec
    FROM emp where deptno = id;   

    FOR i IN 1 .. rec.COUNT LOOP
      PIPE ROW (rec(i));
    END LOOP;
  END get_emp;
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp ( empno, ename, sal, deptno ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 200, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 300, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 150, 30 FROM DUAL;
```

If you do (you have a typo when you call the package function):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table(PKG_EMP.get_emp(30));
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ENAME | SAL | EMPNO
> :---- | :-- | ----:
> Alice | 200 |     1
> Beryl | 300 |     2
> Carol | 150 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a8c0268a3f0fb41edcbe6a0f03fe256)*